# Is it appropriate to store the user Object in localstroage?

Tags: angular, jwt, frontend

I am currently using JWT rails and Angular. After encoding the token with the user Id. Upon a successful signup, I am sending back the user Object and the token which I am using for every subsequent request. Decoding the token can only give me the user ID. In reference of to the current user, should I go ahead to store the user Object on Local storage(I am afraid someone might hijack another person data)? or maybe I should keep making a request with the decoded userId to get the current user(I am afraid this will be too much for the server).

Comment: Is it your web application or hybrid mobile application?

Comment: It's a web application.

Answer (score 1):

Saving User details to local storage is not secured. So you can use crypto-js library and encode it before saving to local storage, decode it before displaying into the DOM.

```
encrypt(data) {

    try {
      return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), this.encryptSecretKey).toString();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  decrypt(data) {

    // avoid UTF-8 Decode Error
    try {
      const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, this.encryptSecretKey);
      if (bytes.toString()) {
        return JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
      }
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: this is wrong and not true. First of all, there is different between encode/decode to encrypt/decrypt, secondly, As long as you do manipulations on the client side, it doesnt matter if you encrypt it or no, if the attacker has access to your local storage, he can decrypt it by him self the same as you did.

Comment: @dAxx_ Thanks for you reply what then is the best solution to handle a current user in a stateless application?